# Discord API - How do I use SocketCommandContext or CommandService.ExecuteAsync to pass additional parameters?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm creating a discord bot through discord's open source library. Here is how all of my commands get created:

```
private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
{
    var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;

    if(message is null || message.Author.IsBot)
        return;

    int argPos = 0;

    if(message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))
    {
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(client, message);
        var result = await commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, services);

        if(!result.IsSuccess)
            Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
    }
}
```

And here is my problem command:

```
public class AddArchiveCommand : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
DiscordSocketClient client;
SocketUserMessage msg;
List<Archive> archiveList;

public AddArchiveCommand(DiscordSocketClient client, SocketUserMessage msg, List<Archive> archiveList)
{
    this.archiveList = archiveList;
}
[Command("addarchive")]
public async Task AddArchiveAsync(ITextChannel sourceChan, ITextChannel destChan)
{
    Archive archive = new Archive(sourceChan.Id, destChan.Id, archiveList);
    archive.AddArchive(); //Using custom method rather than the list add because it check for more logic.
    await ReplyAsync("Now archiving " + sourceChan.Name + " to " + destChan.Name);
}
}
```

I'm trying to pass the List archiveList variable through a constructor from my main class into the command in order to add an archive request to this list. Problem is, I'm not able to do something as simple as "var example = new AddArchiveCommand(archiveList)" due to the nature of how the SocketCommandContext class works.

What am I missing here? Thank you for any explanation. I've been stuck on this for weeks and just need to work with someone on a solution.

Comment: I generally don't see the need for you to be passing around `archiveList`. Simply make an `Archive` service that manages everything to do with your "archiving". The service will maintain your list and calling the Add method would perform whatever necessary logic and inserts as appropriate. This service can be passed to your command module using Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to find a workaround with simply declaring archiveList as a static variable, but I would love to learn how to properly do it using services. I'll do some research. :)

Comment: Yeah, I considered adding "just make it static" as an alternative, but I feel like that while that works, it's not the best solution to your issue. It's definitely an option though.

Comment: You can take a look at the [Dependency injection](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/commands/dependency-injection.html) sample, it should give you some insight on how to use it.